# Blank lines are removed in the HTML <pre> tags in IE10

Tags: html, tags, internet-explorer-10

Empty lines inside the  tag are displayed ok in the latest Chrome and Opera browsers, but in IE 10 they are removed. Is it a known issue, or is there a CSS or another setting to display the tag contents "as is" properly in all browsers including IE?

Comment: Not reproducible. Please show a demo document and explain how the line breaks in it have been produced. Is CR LF or CR or LF or something else used as line break?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, see this: http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx (see the second code snippet, "protected override void OnCellPainting").

Comment: Normal Windows CR/LF's are used as line breaks.

Comment: OK, I can confirm that the problem exists on IE 10. No apparent reason: the `pre` element in it, when written as an HTML document with no other content and no styling, works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange bug in IE 10. Observations on it:

1. Appears when a line consists of space characters only (not for a completely empty line; the page mentioned has lines consisting of one space only).
2. Appears when the doctype declaration is for XHTML 1.0 Transitional (but not with `<!doctype html>` and not without any doctype).
3. Appears both in standards mode and in quirks mode.
4. Keeps appearing when browser is set to emulate (via “Document mode” in F12 settings) IE 9 or IE 8, but not when set to emulate IE 7 or IE 5.
5. Also appears for a `div` element when `white-space: pre` is set on it.

Speculation: When IE 10 tries to deal with XHTML, it gets confused with white space processing somehow.

Workaround: Replace the lines with spaces only by completely empty lines.

Comment: Yes, this workaround with removing spaces in empty lines helped. But now I need to review all other pages and "fix" them accordingly. Damn IE - what surprises did it prepare for us in the future releases? ;)